# Filter list of dictionaries based on keys with one nested dictionary

Tags: python, list, dictionary

Example:

```
[{"a":{"x":13, "y":32, "z":33}, "b":5, "c":7, "d":8, "e":9}, {"a":{"x":18, "y":28, "z":38}, "b":57, "c":77, "d":87, "e":97}, {"a":{"x":17, "y":72, "z":73}, "b":58, "c":70, "d":80, "e":90}, ...]
```

This is just a small sample set, but what I would like is a list with a filtered list of items in each dictionary such as below:

Sample Output:

```
[{"x":13, "b":5, "e"9}, {"x":18, "b":57, "e"97}, {"x":17, "b":58, "e"90}, ...]
```

I can filter it down to the following:

```
[{"a":{"x":13, "y":32, "z":33}, "b":5, "e":9}, {"a":{"x":18, "y":28, "z":38}, "b":57, "e":97}, {"a":{"x":17, "y":72, "z":73}, "b":58, "e":90}, ...]
```

using the following code

```
for i in range(len(results)):
    desired_keys = ['a', 'b', 'e']
    bigdict = all_results[i]
    filtered = {x: bigdict[x] for x in desired_keys if x in bigdict}
```

but have yet to be able to figure out how to get the one element of the nested dictionary out.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You cannot just use your approach since it only works for top-level keys. You will need to specify each key and how to access it from the nested dictionary:

```
>>> [{'x': e['a']['x'], 'b': e['b'], 'e': e['e']} for e in results]
[{'x': 13, 'b': 5, 'e': 9}, {'x': 18, 'b': 57, 'e': 97}, {'x': 17, 'b': 58, 'e': 90}, ...]
```

Comment: Thank you! This is exactly what I was looking for. Thank you for the help!

Answer (score 0):

As mentioned, all the items in the nested dictionaries must be visited.

This recursive approach

```
vals = [{"a":{"x":13, "y":32, "z":33}, "b":5, "c":7, "d":8, "e":9}, {"a":{"x":18, "y":28, "z":38}, "b":57, "c":77, "d":87, "e":97}, {"a":{"x":17, "y":72, "z":73}, "b":58, "c":70, "d":80, "e":90}]

def get_items(d, keys):
 res = dict()
 for k, v in d.items():
  if isinstance(v, dict):
   res.update(get_items(v, keys))
  elif k in keys:
   res[k] = v
 return res

r = [get_items(d, {'x','b', 'e'}) for d in vals]
print(r)
```

produces

```
[{'x': 13, 'b': 5, 'e': 9}, {'x': 18, 'b': 57, 'e': 97}, {'x': 17, 'b': 58, 'e': 90}]
```

Note: make sure the keys do not appear more than once in any given path along the nested dictionaries.

Answer (score 0):

Another possible recursive approach with a generator function:

```
def get_vals(d, to_find):
   for a, b in d.items():
     if a in to_find:
        yield (a, b)
     yield from [] if not isinstance(b, dict) else get_vals(b, to_find)

data = [{"a":{"x":13, "y":32, "z":33}, "b":5, "c":7, "d":8, "e":9}, {"a":{"x":18, "y":28, "z":38}, "b":57, "c":77, "d":87, "e":97}, {"a":{"x":17, "y":72, "z":73}, "b":58, "c":70, "d":80, "e":90}]
result = [dict(get_vals(i, ['x', 'b', 'e'])) for i in data]
```

Output:

```
[{'x': 13, 'b': 5, 'e': 9}, {'x': 18, 'b': 57, 'e': 97}, {'x': 17, 'b': 58, 'e': 90}]
```